# \newcommand isn't working

Tags: macros

I often use minipages aligned to the top using the package `adjustbox` and the code:

```
    \noindent\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}

    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}

    \end{minipage}}
```

I would like to create a command so I don't have to write that every time. I tried:

```
    \newcommand{\mini2}[4]{%
    \noindent\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
    #2
    \end{minipage}} 
    \hfill
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{#2\linewidth}
    #4
    \end{minipage}}
```

I would like to write inside my document something like that

```
    \mini2{0.5}{0.5}{something}{something else}
```

to have two minipages vertically aligned to the top.

Problem: My `\newcommand` is not working, and I can't find why.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You cannot have numbers in the macro names. So `\newcommand{\mini2}{...}` won't work regardless of what `...` is.

Comment: Tank you @marmot

Comment: Besides that you cannot have digits in multi-letter-command-names your command doesn't use the argument `#3` at all. Seems to be a typo/seems  `#2` is also used in the place where `#3` should be used. Also make sure to end lines where LaTeX due to `\endlinechar` might place an undesired space with comment-chars (`%`).

Answer (score 1):

Following you idea, try the following

```
\newcommand{\minii}[4]{%
    \noindent\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
    #3
    \end{minipage}} 
    \hfill
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{#2\linewidth}
    #4
    \end{minipage}}
```

However, I guess that the following suggestion would be a clearer code

```
\def\beginmini#1{%
   \noindent
   \adjustbox{valighn=t}{%
   \begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
   }

\def\endmini{%
   \end{minipage}
```

And then you could simply

```
\beginmini{<your value>}
   <your text>
\endmini
%
\beginmini{<your other value>}
   <your other text>
\endmini
```